# POST without reloading entire webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make a simple post method with the `requests` module, like this :

```
 s=requests.Session() 

 s.post(link,data=payload)
```

In order to do it properly, the payload is an id from the page itself, and it's generated in every access to the page.

So I need to POST without reloading the entire webpage so i can get the right id .

Answer (score 1):

Is this code in a view?

If yes, I'd advise you to create an Ajax view receiving this POST and send the payload from the page using javascript as Ajax.

This way on success, you can get the right id in the response of that view without reloading the page.

Comment: what you mean exactly by "code in a view " ?
it's a login page and have a variable that generated for anyone access it , you can get it from the page source code if that what you meant :
 
`r=requests.get(link)
r.text`


Ajax view ? never heard of , i'm just familiar with requests module
mmmm so it's a little complicated task to do ?

Comment: a "view" is the method or class which will handle a given page. Ajax is widely used for websites, especially to avoid reloading the pages.

Comment: ah ok , i'm sending this request from my personal computer

Comment: how i can use ajax with requests there is any sort of guides to do so ?

Comment: No, in your case, you are only using requests in a python script it seems, to get the id, so you must do your post and read the entire response, unfortunately. If you were doing this in a page you created which also hits a backend view you created, then you could just implement some jquery Ajax in your page which hits your view where you post to that site using requests.

Comment: my page ? it's not my page i have no control over the page i'm sending this request to. i'm just looking for a way to `s.get(link)` get the id then `s.post(link,data=id) ` without reloading for the id to work